# How to convert a single GeoDataFrame column from binary to decimal?

Tags: binary, gis, geopandas

I have GeoDataFrame where a new column 'total' was created, where the column returns a sum of values from a column within the data set. That singular column output is in binary and I need to convert the entire column output to decimal.

Have tried `frombinaryToDecimal` and `int("total")` for the following script:

```
import geopandas
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

df = geopandas.read_file("Traps_records_4th_April_Pulse.csv")
df["total"] = ""
trap_ids = df["trap nid"].unique()
for trap in trap_ids:
    rows = df.loc[df['trap nid'] == trap]
    df.loc[df['trap nid'] == trap, 'total'] = rows["strikes"].sum()
print(df)

int_total = int("total")
print(int_total)

df.to_csv('modified.csv')
```

% where the output looks like:

```
    trap condition      notes Images geometry        total  
0               OK                       None          100  
1               OK                       None       110011  
2               OK                       None          111  
3               OK                       None         1101  
4               OK                       None        10100  
..             ...        ...    ...      ...          ...  
771             OK                       None            1  
772             OK                       None  10011001111  
773             OK                       None          001  
774             OK                       None      1100010  
775             OK  On ground            None            0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the apply method for that

```
import pandas as pd

# create sample data
total = [100, 110011, 111]
df = pd.DataFrame(total, columns=['total'])
print(df)
```

output:

```
    total
0     100
1  110011
2     111
```

conversion with int using base 2

```
df.total = df.total.apply(lambda x: int(str(x), 2))
print(df)
```

output

```
   total
0      4
1     51
2      7
```